# How to count each field in php

Tags: php

I have the below code:

```
function cat_fields($fields)
{
global $cfg;
$fields['cat_furl'] = str_replace('%cat_safename%', $fields['cat_safename'], $cfg->getVar('urlformat_cat'));
$fields['cat_furl'] = $cfg->getVar('site_url') . str_replace('{cat_safename}', $fields['cat_safename'], $fields['cat_furl']);
$fields['cat_flink'] = '<a id="a'  . count($fields) .  '" href="' . $fields['cat_furl'] . '" title="' . $fields['cat_title'] . '">' . $fields['cat_name'] . '</a>';
return $fields;
}
```

And i am trying to count each field of `$fields['cat_flink'] = '<a id="a'  . count($fields) .  '"` I tried with `id="a'  . count($fields) .  '"` but it's returning the total number of field instead of counting them. How can i count them `EACH`.

Should be

```
<a id="a1"....>
<a id="a2"....>
```

Instead it's echoing me

```
<a id="15"....>
<a id="15"....>
..... and so on
```

Please help me on this matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to count *all* the fields in your array; Quoted from the [PHP Manual](https://www.php.net/count):

> Counts all elements in an array, or something in an object.

To get indices (i.e. the numbers you're looking for), you will have to set a starting number and loop over all your fields until you've got them all, and increment that number everytime your walk through the loop.

Your method however, seems to be for only one iteration, which means you would have to store your number elsewhere. A good way to do this would be adding the number as a parameter to your function:

```
function cat_fields($fields, $number)
{
global $cfg;
$fields['cat_furl'] = str_replace('%cat_safename%', $fields['cat_safename'], $cfg->getVar('urlformat_cat'));
$fields['cat_furl'] = $cfg->getVar('site_url') . str_replace('{cat_safename}', $fields['cat_safename'], $fields['cat_furl']);
$fields['cat_flink'] = '<a id="a'  . $number .  '" href="' . $fields['cat_furl'] . '" title="' . $fields['cat_title'] . '">' . $fields['cat_name'] . '</a>';
return $fields;
}
```

Having done that you should edit the loop (I presume) you're using to call the function multiple times:

```
for ($i = 1; $i < count($yourArray); $i++) {
    // code
    $foo = cat_fields($yourArray, $i);
    // more code
}
```

Hope that helps.

**EDIT**:

I've edited the pastebin from lines 131-141:

```
if(($rs = $db->execute($sql)) && (!$rs->EOF))
{
    $i = 1;
    while(!$rs->EOF)
    {
        $rs->fields = seoscripts_prepare_cat_fields($rs->fields, $i);

        $tpl->assign_array_d('tool_category_row', $rs->fields);
        $tpl->parse_d('tool_category_row');
        $rs->MoveNext();
        $i += 1;
    }
}
```

Comment: I tied this on the loop `for ($i = 1; $i < count($fields['cat_furl']); $i++) {
    // code
    $foo = seoscripts_prepare_cat_fields($fields['cat_furl'], $i);
    // more code
}` Tried it but it only echo's `<a id="a">` doesn't do anything. I added the loop and after and before the function. Sorry i am a noob.

Comment: Did you add the parameter to your function, though? It appears that the function isn't using the number. Might also be that number is an integer and in that case you could try adding `strval()` around it.

Comment: Ah you added the loop under your function, but I'm talking about the loop where you're calling this function on your site.

Comment: and it's getting called in widget_catmenu.tpl file with the code `<li>{cat_flink}</li>`, and this file is getting called in `layout_default.tpl` like this     `<div class="ktmsg">
      {seoscriptsCatMenu()}
    </div>`

Comment: Ah, don't need to add anymore the for loop, let me test.

Comment: Working fantastic. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Counting like that`count($fields)` returns the numbers of fields you have you need to add a integer like `i=0;`

and increase it `i++;`

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
function cat_fields($fields)
{
global $cfg;
$fields['cat_furl'] = str_replace('%cat_safename%', $fields['cat_safename'], $cfg->getVar('urlformat_cat'));
$fields['cat_furl'] = $cfg->getVar('site_url') . str_replace('{cat_safename}', $fields['cat_safename'], $fields['cat_furl']);
$str = '';
$i = 0;
foreach($fields as $field)
{
   $str . = '<a id="a'  . $i .  '" href="' . $fields['cat_furl'] . '" title="' . $fields['cat_title'] . '">' . $fields['cat_name'] . '</a>';
   $i++;
}
$fields['cat_flink'] = $str;
return $fields;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    function cat_fields($fields)
        {
        global $cfg;
        $fields['cat_furl'] = str_replace('%cat_safename%', $fields['cat_safename'], $cfg->getVar('urlformat_cat'));
        $fields['cat_furl'] = $cfg->getVar('site_url') . str_replace('{cat_safename}', $fields['cat_safename'], $fields['cat_furl']);
$i=0;
        foreach($fields as $field)
        {
           $fields['cat_flink'] = '<a id="a'.$i.'" href="' . $field['cat_furl'] . '" title="' . $field['cat_title'] . '">' . $field['cat_name'] . '</a>';
i++;
        }
        return $fields;
        }
```

Comment: It send me error `syntax error, unexpected T_INC in.. on line 9` that would be where `i++` it is.

Comment: Ok found where was the problem `i++;` should be `$i++;` still is not echoing correctly, it echo's something like `<a id="a14" title="h" href="h">h</a>`

Comment: ye my bad show me more outputs since I don't know what it is at all

Answer (score 0):

if you are counting an array then

echo count($array);

will give the count of every element in the array.